# Npm command not found after launch build.sh file

Tags: node.js, linux, npm, nvm, git-post-receive

I installed nvm and then installed npm by `nvm install npm`.
Nvm and npm have been installed to my main directory `~/.nvm` and `~/.npm`.
And yes, npm command is correct in every directory in the server on the ssh connection in console.
I added also **build.sh** file where I wrote `npm run prod` command and added this in post-receive git hook.

BUT! When I send new commits to this server, I see in console note like "*npm command not found*".
WHY????
After all, on the server everything is okay!

I tried also move **~/.npm** to **/usr/local/bin**/ but it wasn't help. Probably because **.npm** it is a folder. I don't know...
I solved problem by deleting **.nvm** and **.npm** folders and installing npm through sudo apt-get. I guess it automatically have added needs files in needs directories to make npm command globally available.

In spite of I solved the problem by another way, I want to know what I was doing incorrectly in the first approach, cause maybe in the future I need nvm. Can someone experienced in linux explain me what the problem was?

Comment: * added this in post-receive git hook.* Are you pushing to your server and expecting the server to run a build automatically? If so, what user is the git server running as vs. user you are SSH'ing in as?

Comment: @ta.speot.is , Yes, it is so. I didn't register else users except root. All the steps were under root user

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the absolute path where `npm` command was installed is listen within your `PATH` variable, then make sure you export this variable so your `build.sh` script can see the new value and search for `npm` binary.

```
echo $PATH
export PATH="/path/to/my/installation/:$PATH"
echo $PATH
./build.sh
```